# Laravel 5.8 show, update, delete record form two different table

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show, update and delete record from two different tables. 
Here is show controller function:

```
public function show($user_id)
    {
        //

        $staffinfo = Staff::find($user_id);  // Loading all data from 
        $userinfo = User::find($user_id); 
        return view('staff.view')
        ->with('staffinfo', $staffinfo)
        ->with('userinfo', $userinfo);
    }
```

Here is view.blade.php code:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-dark">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Name</th>
            <td>{{ $staffinfo->name }}</td>
        </tr>        
        <tr>
               <th scope="row">Mobile</th>
               <td>{{ $userinfo->mobile }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Designation</th>
            <td>{{ $staffinfo->designatin }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit and update function in controller:

```
public function edit($user_id)
    {
        //
        $staffinfo = Staff::find($user_id);  // Loading all data from 
        $userinfo = User::find($user_id);
        return view('staff.edit')
        ->with('staffinfo', $staffinfo)
        ->with('userinfo', $userinfo);
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $user_id)
    {
        //
        $staffinfo = Staff::find($user_id);
        $staffinfo->name = $request->input('stfname');
        $staffinfo->user_id = $request->input('stfid');
        $staffinfo->designaton = $request->input('stfdesig');
        $staffinfo->dob = $request->input('staffdob');
        $staffinfo->save();

        $userinfo = User::find($user_id);
        $userinfo->user_id = $request->input('stfid');
        $userinfo->user_type = $request->input('stfdesig');
        $userinfo->mobile = $request->input('staffmobile');
        $userinfo->email = $request->input('staffmail');
        $userinfo->password = $request->input('staffpw');
        $userinfo->save();     
    }
```

edit.blade.php code some part:

```
<h2>Update Staff</h2>
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('staff.update', $staffinfo->user_id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @method('PATCH')
        @csrf
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="stfdesig">Designation</label>
              <input type="text" name="stfdesig" value="{{ $staffinfo->designation }}" class="form-control" id="stfid"

            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label for="stfid">ID</label>
              <input type="text" name="stfid" value="{{ $staffinfo->user_id }}" class="form-control" id="stfid">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="stfname">Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="stfname" value="{{ $staffinfo->name }}" class="form-control" id="stfname">
            </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="stfmobile">Mobile</label>
              <input type="text" name="stfmobile" value="{{ $userinfo->mobile }}" class="form-control" id="stfmobile">
            </div>
        </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </form>
```

View page error:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View:
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\gchsc\resources\views\staff\view.blade.php)

Edit page error:

> Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object (View:
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\gchsc\resources\views\staff\edit.blade.php)

Comment: try referencing all your variables like this:  $staffinfo['name'] .

Comment: @BradGoldsmith No you shouldn't. Laravel gives you objects to work with, not arrays.

Comment: @Riyad are you sure the `staffinfo` (which is the one that's causing the errors) is loaded in both situations? Could be the result is NULL and thus would cause errors.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan yes, it's loaded. I want to know is it the right way to view records from multiple table and edit record of multiple table using single form? I have not created any relation among the tables. I used Elequent.

Comment: @Riyad do the fields you try to access exist in the table? Does `staffinfo` contain the name and user_id fields?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan yes there is field user_id  in staffinfo table aslo in user table. Please check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values using compact()

```
public function show($user_id){

     $staffinfo = Staff::find($user_id);
     $userinfo = User::find($user_id);

     return view('staff.view', compact('staffinfo','userinfo'));
}
```

Comment: You can use all kinds of methods to pass the data to the view, but that isn't the solution for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `->with()` is the method you need to pass data to a view.

As Shanu said, you could use compact.

Or you could simply pass the data to the view in an associative array as the second parameter...

```php
return view('staff.edit', [
    'staffinfo' => $staffinfo,
    'userinfo' => $userinfo
]);
```

Comment: `with` is a valid method of passing data to the view. [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: Weird. I've seen this question asked a few times where people are using `with()` and it's not working. Ah well! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public function show($user_id)
        {
            //

            $staffinfo = Staff::find($user_id);  // Loading all data from 
            $userinfo = User::find($user_id); 
            return view('staff.view')
            ->with('staffinfo', $staffinfo)
            ->with('userinfo', $userinfo);
        }
```

> Is it right way to show records from multiple table in a single view
>   page without creating relation in Model?
>
> Here is view.blade.php code

```
<table class="table table-hover table-dark">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Name</th>
                    <td>{{ $staffinfo->name }}</td>
                </tr>        
                <tr>
                       <th scope="row">Mobile</th>
                       <td>{{ $userinfo->mobile }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Designation</th>
                    <td>{{ $staffinfo->designatin }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think i have got the problem, but can't figure it out. There is
>   user_id field in both user table and staff table. If if send id from
>   view link from index.blade.php then it's work.

```
<a href="/staff/{{$info->id}}">View</a>
```

> If is send user_id then it's not working. Showing above error.

```
<a href="/staff/{{$info->user_id}}">View</a>
```

> how can i send user_id form from view link?